# Create a "clone" of this object, not point to it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Let's say I got a list called

```
myFirstList
```

And then I want to create a copy of that list so I can do some tweaks of my own. So I do this:

```
mySecondList = myFirstList
mySecondList.doTweaks
```

But I noticed that the tweaks also affect the `myFirstList` object! I only want the tweaks to affect the second one...

And afterwards I will want to completely delete `mySecondList`, so I do `mySecondList = Nothing` and I'm good, right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adam Rackis, I don't like your "Of course it does", because it is not at all obvious.

If you have a string variable that you assign to another string variabe, you do not change them both when making changes to one of them. They do not point to the same physical piece of memory, so why is it obvious that classes do?

Also, the thing is not even consistent. In the following case, you will have all elements in the array pointing at the same object (they all end up with the variable Number set to 10:

```
SourceObject = New SomeClass
For i = 1 To 10
   SourceObject.Number = i
   ObjectArray.Add = SourceObject   
Next i
```

BUT, the following will give you 10 different instances:

```
For i = 1 To 10
   SourceObject = New SomeClass
   SourceObject.Number = i
   ObjectArray.Add = SourceObject   
Next i
```

Apparently the scope of the object makes a difference, so it is not at all obvious what happens.

Comment: Yeah it's always seemed counter-intuitive to me too.  It's also amazing that after 10 years there still isn't any easy .NET function or method to do a deep clone.  OK memory was precious back in 2002 when .NET came out, but now?

Answer (score 9):

Here is how you do it:

```
'copy one object to another via reflection properties
For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In originalobject.GetType().GetProperties()
    If p.CanRead Then
        clone.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).SetValue(clone, p.GetValue(OriginalObject, Nothing))
    End If
Next
```

in some cases when the clone object got read-only properties you need to check that first.

```
For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In originalobject.GetType().GetProperties()
    If p.CanRead AndAlso clone.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).CanWrite Then
        clone.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).SetValue(clone, p.GetValue(OriginalObject, Nothing))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Ok, what am I missing here?  "Clone is not declared".

Answer (score 7):

Since you have not divulged the type of item that you are storing n your list, I assume it's something that's implementing IClonable (Otherwise, if you can, implement IClonable, or figure out a way to clone individual item in the list).

Try something like this

```
mySecondList = myFirstList.[Select](Function(i) i.Clone()).ToList()
```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on ***Adam Rackies***' answer I was able to implement the following code using VB.NET.

**My goal was to copy a list of objects that served mainly as data transfer objects (i.e. database data).**  The first the class *dtoNamedClass* is defined and *ShallowCopy* method is added.  A new variable named *dtoNamedClassCloneVar* is created and a LINQ select query is used to copy the object variable dtoNamedClassVar.

**I was able to make changes to *dtoNamedClassCloneVar* without affecting *dtoNamedClassVar***.

```
Public Class dtoNamedClass


    ... Custom dto Property Definitions



  Public Function ShallowCopy() As dtoNamedClass
    Return DirectCast(Me.MemberwiseClone(), dtoNamedClass)
  End Function

End Class


Dim dtoNamedClassVar As List(Of dtoNamedClass) = {get your database data}

Dim dtoNamedClassCloneVar = 
    (From d In Me.dtoNamedClass
        Where {add clause if necessary}
        Select d.ShallowCopy()).ToList
```

Comment: Underrated answer! This helped! Can you elaborate on "how shallow" / "how deep" the copy from `ShallowCopy()` is?

Answer (score 4):

> But I noticed that the tweaks also
>   affect the myFirstList object! I only
>   want the tweaks to affect the second
>   one...

Of course it does.  Both variables are pointing to the **same object** in memory.  Anything you do to the one, happens to the other.

You're going to need to do either a deep clone, or a shallow one, depending on your requirements.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Clone.aspx) should give you a better idea what you need to do

Comment: Very interesting info, okay. Fortunately I managed to find a workaround, but this is nice to know as well :)

Comment: @Adam the link in the linked article to the actual implementation is now broken

Answer (score 4):

Here's an additional approach that some may prefer since System.Reflection can be slow.

You'll need to add the **Newtonsoft.Json** NuGet package to your solution, then:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

And given a class type of `MyClass`, cloning can be as easy as:

```
Dim original as New MyClass
'populate properties of original...
Dim copy as New MyClass
copy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyClass)(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original))
```

So the approach is to first use the JSON converter to serialize the `original` object, and than take that serialized data and deserialize it - specifying the class type - into the class instance `copy`.

The JSON converters are extremely powerful and flexible; you can do all sorts of custom property mappings and manipulations if you need something the basic approach above doesn't seem to address.

Comment: Upvoted because this actually works for me!

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
mySecondList = myFirstList.ToList
```

Answer (score -1):

clone is the object you are attempting to clone to.

```
dim clone as new YourObjectType
```

You declare it like that.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I don't really understand your answer. Are you maybe answering to tolsen64's comment on [deuan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35641516/3982001)?