# How to import properties from one element to another?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I Have Windows Form that has let's say a `TextBox1` and a `Button1`. When the `Button1` is clicked, the new `TextBox2`is created below the initial `TextBox1`. How do i import all properties from `TextBox1` to `TextBox2` so they look the exact same way (size, text, background color, font etc.)?

Comment: You are looking for a so called Memberwise clone. See this thread for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574024/create-a-clone-of-this-object-not-point-to-it

Comment: @MrPaulch It seems that MemberwiseClone() doesn't work for me because it's protected - i get overload resolution failed error

Comment: Yeah, it seems you'll have to create your own derivate of Button, that exposes that method either by shadowing, or a custom wrapper. In your case though it seems to more prudent to use Fabian Biglers proposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reflection to clone the textbox (sorry about C#):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextBox t = (TextBox)CloneObject(textBox1);
}

private object CloneObject(object o)
{
Type t = o.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

Object p = t.InvokeMember("", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, o, null);

foreach(PropertyInfo pi in properties)
{
if(pi.CanWrite)
{
pi.SetValue(p, pi.GetValue(o, null), null);
}
}

return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Fabian Bigler for his C# code. Here's the VB.net equivalent:

```
 Private Function CloneControl(ByVal control As Object) As Object
    Dim type As Type = control.GetType()
    Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = type.GetProperties()
    Dim retObject As Object = type.InvokeMember("", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, Nothing, control, Nothing)
    For Each p As PropertyInfo In properties
         If p.CanWrite Then
              p.SetValue(retObject, p.GetValue(control, Nothing), Nothing)
         End If
     Next
     Return retObject
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Combobox3 = DirectCast(CloneControl(ComboBox2), ComboBox)
End Sub
```