# Why my items in List(of T) updates without me updating them? - VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list(T) where i loop for each item and compare these items to other list items.
After first loop the list that i looped updated its items with different values.
What is going on?

Im loopin **listOfPoz** and to match value to **protOBJlist** items properties.

After that i put matched items into a new list(T) **newListOfProtObj** but after first loop the **protOBJlist** items changes which is wierd and not needed.

```
    Public Function ParsePozList(ByVal protOBJlist As List(Of DEL_Protokoli.ProtOBJ), ByVal listOfPoz As List(Of String)) As List(Of DEL_Protokoli.ProtOBJ)

        'ByVal ProtACADdrawObj As DEL_Protokoli.ACADdrawProtOBJ
        Dim ProtInst As New DEL_Protokoli
        Dim newListOfProtObj As New List(Of DEL_Protokoli.ProtOBJ)

        For Each item In listOfPoz

            If Not item = "" Then

                Select Case ProtInst.ParsePozNr(item)
                    Case DEL_Protokoli.PozObj.C1
                        'izvelk visu pozīciju
                        Dim lol = (From i In protOBJlist Where i.PozicijasNr = item Select i).ToList.FirstOrDefault

                        If Not lol Is Nothing Then
                            newListOfProtObj.Add(lol)
                        End If

                    Case DEL_Protokoli.PozObj.C2
                        'izvelk visu gray pozīciju

                        Dim lol = (From i In protOBJlist Where i.PozicijasNr = item.Split(".")(DEL_Protokoli.PozObj.C1) Select i).ToList.FirstOrDefault

                        If Not lol Is Nothing Then


                            Dim lol2 = (From i In lol.Ipasnieki Where i.PozicijasNr = item).ToList
                            Dim lolmeg As New DEL_Protokoli.ProtOBJ

                            lolmeg = lol
                            lolmeg.Ipasnieki = lol2
                            lolmeg.PozicijasNr = item


                            newListOfProtObj.Add(lolmeg)
                        End If


                    Case DEL_Protokoli.PozObj.C3
                        'izvelk tikai vienu īpašnieku

                        Dim pozSplit = item.Split(".")(DEL_Protokoli.PozObj.C1)

                        Dim lol = (From i In protOBJlist Where i.PozicijasNr = pozSplit Select i).ToList.FirstOrDefault

                        If Not lol Is Nothing Then
                            Dim lol2 = (From i In lol.Ipasnieki Where i.Nr = item).ToList
                            Dim lolmeg As New DEL_Protokoli.ProtOBJ

                            lolmeg = lol
                            lolmeg.Ipasnieki = lol2
                            lolmeg.PozicijasNr = item

                            newListOfProtObj.Add(lolmeg)
                        End If

                End Select


            End If
        Next

        Return newListOfProtObj


    End Function
```

[First loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSl8n.png)
[Second Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8azL.png)

Check the images

**

> The solution, thanks to the guys in comments, has been found.

**

All i had to do is assign the old object properties to the new one. The "=" does not help if you trying to assign all the properties, you gotta do them one by one.

```
Case DEL_Protokoli.PozObj.C3
                        'izvelk tikai vienu īpašnieku

                        Dim pozSplit = item.Split(".")(DEL_Protokoli.PozObj.C1)
                        Dim lol As New DEL_Protokoli.ProtOBJ
                        lol = (From i In protOBJlist Where i.PozicijasNr = pozSplit Select i).ToList.FirstOrDefault

                        If Not lol Is Nothing Then
                            Dim lol2 = (From i In lol.Ipasnieki Where i.Nr = item).ToList
                            'Dim lolmeg As New DEL_Protokoli.ProtOBJ

                            'lolmeg = lol
                            'lolmeg.Ipasnieki = lol2
                            'lolmeg.PozicijasNr = item

                            Dim lolgala As New DEL_Protokoli.ProtOBJ With {
                          .Hidden = lol.Hidden,
                          .Ipasnieki = lol2,
                          .PozicijasNosaukums = lol.PozicijasNosaukums,
                          .PozicijasNr = item,
                          .Type = lol.Type,
                          .ZGnodalijums = lol.ZGnodalijums}

                            newListOfProtObj.Add(lolgala)
                        End If
```

Something like that.

Comment: Instead of writing `lolmeg = lol`, you need to copy the individual properties from `lol` to `lolmeg`. For more information, please start with [Create a “clone” of this object, not point to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574024/create-a-clone-of-this-object-not-point-to-it).

Comment: It is important to understand that OOP is based on the behaviour of real-world objects. If you want to understand the behaviour of programming objects, think about how objects behave in the real world. Let's say that I am on your basketball team and someone else's football team. I front up to you and you give me a basketball uniform to put on. I then front up to my football team coach and they give me a football uniform to put on. If I front up to you again, would you be surprised to see me in a football uniform? Of course not. I am one person, even if I'm in two teams. This is the same.

Comment: `(From i In protOBJlist Where i.PozicijasNr = item Select i).ToList.FirstOrDefault` would be better written as `protOBJlist.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.PozicijasNr = item)`

Comment: @Andrew-Morton thank you guys, your comments helped me to fix my problem and understand more about these things.